# how to split multiple cells in a row into multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have a set of numbers in different cells in a row like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

all numbers in a different cell.

I want to achieve this:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Since I have more than 10 numbers, I want to automate this
Is there a quick way to do this? thank you.

+
copying like 100 columns and pasting it into a row works using a transpose function, but when a column reaches like 40,000. It doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: May be you need to write a small macro to do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in Sheet1 and first row.
Output will be in Sheet2.
Try this code and change if required.

```
Sub splitcolumn()
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i + 1)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        i = i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Make sure you have Sheet1 and Sheet2 created in your file before running this code. Also you have some data in first row of Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your have the numbers 1 to 10 in `A1:J10`:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J  
1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
2
```

Now type in these formulas in the cells indicated:

```
A2 = OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW()*2-4)
B2 = OFFSET($B$1,0,ROW()*2-4)
```

Now drag the formulas down as far as you need them.

**Notes**

`ROW()*2-4)` is a regression equation to match the row number to the offset required.